# Babel error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I'm getting an error from Babel when trying to compile my JSX code into JS. I'm new to react so apologies if this is an obvious issue, I wasn't able to find anything about it that seemed related. I'm attempting to use props in this chunk of code, and pass a pageTitle prop to my FieldContainer component. This is giving me an issue, though, that isn't letting the code compile to JS. I discovered in my searching that prop values should be passed between `{}`, but adding these did not help. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image: Babel Error]

Comment: Please include the actual code in the question.

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^6.4.0", //Downgrade babelify might help in package.json and run npm install

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do here, but as the error says, the value of an attribute must be an expression `{foo}` or quoted text `"foo"`.

In this case

```
Child={<LoginForm />}
```

or

```
Child={LoginForm}
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: This was it! Wow. I assumed you didn't need the {} with variable names. Silly me. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.

Comment: if the argument value is numeric, how I supposed to do that? `<foo top={30}>`? `<foo top=30>` doesn't compile whereas  `<foo top="30">` but that value treated as string, is giving some odd behavior on control.

Comment: @Jack `<foo top={30}>` seems fine.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks, I thought that was hacky or something... I knew to react

Answer (score 11):

I got this error because I failed to quote a property inside of the JSX:

```
<span aria-hidden=true ...
```

should have been

```
<span aria-hidden="true" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just faced same issue, I was writing

`component="Contacts"`

resolved it by rewriting it as:

`component={Contacts}`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while passing some props to the dynamically rendered list.

```
<ul>
  {myList.map(item => <li> <CustomComponent data=item /> </li>)}
</ul>
```

I assumed the dynamic property (`item`) would be evaluated as I already have everything wrapped in `{}`. But that's not true, I had to wrap each dynamic property in `{}` too.

```
<ul>
  {myList.map(item => <li> <CustomComponent data={item} /> </li>)}
</ul>
```